# cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer ENCODING_ERR

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm trying to use $cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer but I'm getting the following error

I tried some solutions from the forum but without success

```
function getFileBlob(url, cb) {
console.log(url);
var path = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length);
console.log('path', path);
    console.log('file', filename);
    $cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(path, filename)
            .then(function (success) {
                var blob = new Blob([success], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
                cb(blob);
            }, function (error) {
                onsole.error(error);
                cb(null);
            });
 }
```

Error:
FileError code:5, message:"ENCODING_ERR"

Console.logs:

My url: `/file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.xx443164/cache/.Pic.jpg`

var path:`/file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.xx443164/cache/`

var file: `.Pic.jpg`

I'm testing on an android

Comment: Please let me know if you were able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you, if you need to get your photo as a blob type

```
    var photo = url; // your photo                 
 var mainDic = photo.substring(0, photo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
     mainArchive = photo.substring(photo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, photo.length);
 $cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(mainDic, mainArchive).then(function(success) {
     var blob = new Blob([success], {
         type: 'image/jpeg'
     });
     // now blob is your photo as blob type
 }, function(error) {
     console.error(error);
 });
```